# Real-Time Shared GPS Location in QField

Tags: qgis, gps, qfield, geolocation

Is it somehow possible to visualize the real-time GPS locations of other persons involved in the same QField project (synchronized with QFieldCLoud)?
Maybe using external devices or additional apps/plugins?
And if not, could it be a feature to be added in the next future?

Comment: Feature suggestions should be added to git hub, here: https://github.com/opengisch/QField/discussions?page=3

Comment: It's not in QField, but you can share your location via google maps.

Comment: @Oisin maybe I will follow your advice and post it on git-hub.